# Creating action in Object Orientated Programming

Tags: java, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I just started an Object Orientated Programming class. I'm trying to write a program that adds a `Customer` to a `System` by giving name and age parameters, but duplicates are not allowed.

If I were writing this Java code normally, I would simply create a class named `Customer` with name and age instance variables with a method called `new()` which would create a new customer.

But since this isn't a list or anything, instead simply adding a `Customer` to a `System`, where do I write the method to not allow duplicates?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest that you create a `new()` method inside a class that's responsible for creating new instances; that's what the `new` keyword is for.

Comment: Well, it sounds like the `System` class you have needs to have an `addCustomer` method. That method should handle the logic of checking duplicates, since `Customer` should have no knowledge of the `System`.

Comment: Can't your `System` just have a `Set<Customer>` member?  Then, as along as `Customer` implements `equals()` and `hashCode`, it should be fine.

Comment: You wouldn't create a method called `new()`. You can't.

Comment: Sounds like you trying to create a [factory pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html)

Answer (score 1):

Create field in `System` or make `System` extend `Set` and override `equals()` function in `Customer` class to compare fields that can't be duplicates.